# Как в Django (фильтр) вывести все записи совпадающие с запросом?

Tags: python, django, filter, фильтр, queryset

Вывести все записи совпадающие с запросом (частичное или полное совпадение), поиск проводится по нескольким полям.
Например:
Запрос: "Антон Сахаров стал доктором в прошлом году"
Поля: name, surname, text, info, tag
Запис в бд:
1)name = "Антон", surname="Иванов", text="Доктор наук уволился с работы", info= "Следующий год, год семьи";
2)name = "Сергей", surname="Сахаров", text="Нынче тяжело работать", info= "Что-то там";
3)name = "Герман", surname= "Петров", text="Погода плохая, идет дождь", info= "Следующий";

Должно выводится 1 и 2 (есть частичное совпадение)

Comment: Пример на PHP: https://phppot.com/demo/datatables-server-side-processing-using-php-with-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1. совпадение по любому из слов

```
   from django.db.models import Q
   q_list = Q()
   for word in 'текст для поиска'.split():
        q_list |= Q(name__icontains=word)
        q_list |= Q(surname__icontains=word)
        q_list |= Q(text__icontains=word)
    queryset = ModelName.objects.filter(q_list)
```

Только нужно учитывать, если используешь SQlite, то там, насколько я помню, не работает поиск без учета регистра для кириллицы

подробней про Q() можно почитать:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Вариант 2.
Если я правильно понял, то получается, нужно что бы каждое из слов было в результирующем запросе хоть в одном из полей, тогда можно попробовать вот так:

```
   from django.db.models import Q
   queryset = ModelName.objects.all()
   for word in 'текст для поиска'.split():
        q_list = Q()
        q_list |= Q(name__icontains=word)
        q_list |= Q(surname__icontains=word)
        q_list |= Q(text__icontains=word)
        queryset = queryset.filter(q_list)
```

Comment: Андрей, огромное спасибо!

Comment: https://phppot.com/demo/datatables-server-side-processing-using-php-with-mysql/ - как такую же сделать? Т.е. вывод совподения по всем словам запроса.

Comment: так я ведь в и написал код, который будет искать совпадение по всем словам запроса. вместо 'текст для поиска' введи данные, которые ввел пользователь. Если у тебя полей больше, то добавляй строчку `q_list |= Q(<имяполя>__icontains=word)` дальше тебе уже нужно будет дорабатывать Javascript, что бы все отражалось как в твоем примере без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Я сделал как ты описал, но проблема в том, что возвращаются все записи где встречается слово из word (это список слов, ну ты понял), а надо чтобы отображались только те записи где слова из word комбинируются. Если не сложно проверь следующие запросы на https://phppot.com/demo/datatables-server-side-processing-using-php-with-mysql/ (Запрос 1: ba 66 0 и запрос 2: ba 66 02), потом сравни результаты. По-другому не знаю как описать.

Comment: Убедительная просьба

Comment: Вод фото (обрати внимание как было и как стало. Было две записи, после добавления 2 осталась одна): https://ibb.co/BB22kHM
https://ibb.co/st9G1ht

Comment: я поменял ответ, посмотри второй вариант

Comment: Да, второй вариант именно, то что надо. Супер! Спасибо тебе добрый человек!

Comment: Давненько я не смотрел спецификацию split(), а бывает полезно). код можно немного упростить. я обновил ответ

Comment: Супер! Спасибо! ;-)